# What is the difference between Regularization, optimization, and pruning?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, regularization, pruning

- [Regularization Techniques in Deep Learning](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/fundamentals-deep-learning-regularization-techniques/) = reduces or solves overfitting problem.
- [Optimizing Neural Network Structures with Keras-Tuner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvC15l4CY1Q&t=14s) = reduces the connections and number of neurons for optimal performance.
- [Pruning in Keras example](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/pruning_with_keras) =

According to [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220829564_Pruning_and_Regularization_Techniques_for_Feed_Forward_Nets_Applied_on_a_Real_World_Data_Base) pruning and regularization are types of Optimization:

[image]

However, I am confused because the above three links don't conform to the diagram's terminologies.

What is the difference between Regularization, optimization, and pruning?

Are they different or the same?

Comment: Rather than pasting links to videos, please provide a text description of the content—helpers on the site shouldn't be expected to watch the whole video to see what it's talking about.

Comment: Ordinary Least Squares regression is based on optimization (as its name indicates), but what would "pruning" even mean?  You (metaphorically) compare apples, oranges, and motor vehicles, which makes little sense.

Comment: @whuber, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220829564_Pruning_and_Regularization_Techniques_for_Feed_Forward_Nets_Applied_on_a_Real_World_Data_Base

Comment: My point is that "pruning" makes no sense in many statistical settings.  It refers to operations on trees.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided much information within your post but I'll try to answer just based on the title.

[optimization](/questions/tagged/optimization) is a fancy way of saying "make it better" - this could refer to reducing variance (i.e. solving for over-fitting), reducing bias, or simply making your model more accurate.

Pruning in `keras` refers to removing unnecessary neurons and weights from a deep learning model. It's a way to make neural networks smaller, faster, and more efficient. Pruning also refers to a specific method to reduce over-fitting in a random forest model (which is different from pruning in `keras`).

[regularization](/questions/tagged/regularization) is a method to solve for [overfitting](/questions/tagged/overfitting), like you mentioned.

It may help to clarify where your confusion lies.

Comment: [This article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220829564_Pruning_and_Regularization_Techniques_for_Feed_Forward_Nets_Applied_on_a_Real_World_Data_Base) says that regularization and pruning are a kind of optimization.

Comment: It's also helpful to appreciate that 'optimize' is a suitcase-word.